# How changing the video quality works while watching video online?

Tags: design, video

How does changing the video quality works behind the scene? Suppose I am watching a video on youtube (I will use YT as an example in this question) and suddenly my internet speed becomes slow, in that case YT automatically (or sometimes I as a user) change the quality to some lower resolution. But the video does not start from the start but it keeps going on from the point of change.
Now that brings me to a few questions.

1. How the transmission of different resolution videos are supported behind the scene? My guess is Transcoding.
2. Are there different actual videos files stored on servers? If yes, does YT seeks the different resolution files and starts transmitting from selected resolution file ? If it does then, YT must have some pretty solid indexing of files and the content of files, because finding the right data in a file can be very challenging (i.e. finding the content after 12:45 length of video).
3. If there are not different actual videos files stored on servers? Then YT must be using different codecs to encode the content for different resolution and then client(youtube.com) must be choosing the same codec to run the video?

Apologies if my questions seem naive but I did some research on this topic but could not find any good resource on how it all works under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Youtube stores multiple versions of the video, with varying resolutions. It would take huge amounts of processing power to transcode the videos on the fly. It is much more sensible to just transcode them once and store them separately. Also, it is much easier to work with content delivery networks, as those are optimized for storing and delivering files.

Seeking in video files is trivial. Most video containers support seeking by storing index of timestamps of where in the file should reading start to play from that timestamp. Even if you play video on your own machine, selecting a time won't seek through the whole file, but use that index to start reading from specific position in the file. So it is trivial for youtube to start streaming from position of the file once it has the right file.

Comment: Indeed. Most container formats have timestamps, at least optionally. And even if they don't, it would be trivial to create a separate timestamp database while you are transcoding the video anyway. (In fact, it would make sense to do so, since it would allow you to correlate index positions between the different resolutions in a database.) Also, if the video is constant bit rate encoded, then you can simply "guess" at the right position at the file (e.g. if the file is 1GiB, the video is 1h long, and you want to jump to 0:15, it's a pretty good guess it'll be near 256MiB into the file).

Comment: And even for variable bit rate encoding, the bit rate will average out over large portions of the file, so you will be getting pretty close.